# Overloading operator-> when operator* returns temporary

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, temporary-objects

I have two classes with the following structure:

```
struct A {
  A transform() const;
};

struct B {
  // returns a temporary A
  A operator*() const;
};
```

The `*` operator may look a little weird here, but given the context of its usage is actually pretty natural. In fact, `B` really exists only to provide some syntatic sugar for an embedded language, so it's methods and operators are designed to give desired look to code. Given `B b`, getting the associated `A` is fast, `*b`. I sometimes want to call the transform on `A` immediately. Currently, this requires some extra parentheses `(*b).transform()`. There seems like a natural simplification, namely `b->transform()`. But `operator ->` is supposed to return a pointer and `operator *` is returns a temporary. How can I implement an overload like that?

Comment: It's a hack, but you could add a `A* operator->() { return this; }` to `A`. It's a bad hack, but your `operator*` already has semantics different from the built-in operator, since it returns a prvalue (not an lvalue).

Comment: @dyp And then I can write something like this: `*b->transform()`? That's not too bad, except that in this case `A` is a class that used in libraries shared in many projects and I'd rather than not do something weird to it. `B` can be as unintuitive as it would like.

Comment: No, you'd write `b->transform()`, [see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87bb2ef2ab2ca1a1). You could also return an intermediate type from `B::operator->` that has this member `A* operator->() { return /*something*/; }`, where `something` is a data member.

Comment: [Live example with intermediate type](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/206361ce92a1fc99)

Comment: I would make a separate proxy struct type, rather than mess with class `A`.  It's smelly to have `a.m` and `a->m` mean the same thing.

Comment: @aschepler Like in my latest live example?

Comment: I see. With the intermediate type, it's a fine solution!

Comment: Yes, exactly. Crossing comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not responsible for any confusions that arise from changing the value category of the overloaded operators from their built-in counterparts.

```
struct just_some_type
{
    int m;

    int transform() { return m; }
};

// the intermediate helper stops the recurring application of ->
// if the lhs of -> is of a class type
struct intermediate_helper
{
    just_some_type member;

    just_some_type* operator->() { return &member; }
};

struct ptr_like
{
    just_some_type operator*()
    { return {42}; }

    intermediate_helper operator->()
    { return {{42}}; }
};
```

Usage example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto p = ptr_like{};
    std::cout << (*p).transform() << "\n";
    std::cout << p->transform() << "\n";
}
```

**Important note:** the object acted upon in `p->` is an lvalue, as the built-in `->` is applied to a pointer! E.g. if you qualify `transform` with an lvalue-ref like `int transform() &;`, then the version `(*p).transform()` will fail to compile, but `p->transform()` still is legal.

Comment: Obviously, you might want to add const overloads, if appropriate.