# How to overload operator-> for iterator, when operator* returns std::make_pair

Tags: c++, c++17

Given `auto iterator::operator*() { return std::make_pair(1, 2.0); }`, I can write `(*it).first`. But how do I write `operator->` such that `it->first` also works?

[Overloading operator-> when operator* returns temporary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028313/overloading-operator-when-operator-returns-temporary) applies, because `std::make_pair` indeed return a temporary. I of course know the type is a `std::pair<int,float>` in this simple example, but that's not generally the case. And the answer given in the linked question assumes that you can spell out the type.

I've come up with this dirty hack:

```
auto iterator::operator->() {
        auto ptr = new auto(this->operator*());
        return std::unique_ptr<decltype(*ptr)>(ptr);
        // The `decltype` is needed because `unique_ptr` intentionally has no deduction guides
        // it can't distinguish `new` and `new[`]`.
```

}

This uses the fact that `operator->` can forward to another type, as suggested by the other question, and `std::unique_ptr` does implement `operator->`. I obviously can't return `ptr` directly, that would leak. But still - that's an unnecessary heap allocation. N3664 allows it to be eliminated, but I'd rather not rely on that.

Is there any other way in which I can write `operator->` to forward to `operator*`, without having to name the type of expression inside `operator*`?

Comment: What is your iterator's `reference` type?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Is that type still required in C++17? I thought `std::iterator` was deprecated for that reason - if you don't need the nested types anymore, inheriting from `std::iterator`  is not giving you anything. And that would be because we can now `auto` pretty much anything. And for the same reason I'm trying to not spell out types where I can avoid it.

Comment: The iterator categories still require that the `iterator_traits` types are available, whether through the default (ie: checking your iterator's members) or through an explicit specialization of `iterator_traits`.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Ah, good catch. Both ways are optional, but I still need to choose one of the two. The depreciation doesn't affect that. Anyway, it's by necessity a `LegacyInputIterator`, I think, since `operator*` generates a temporary. You can't write back to that. And the `reference` member will be tricky to name, it might require another `decltype`.

Comment: You don't have to be able to write to input iterators, hence the name.

Comment: Can’t you just make the helper a template to avoid spelling out a type name?